# Scala (Easy)Mocking default method parameters

Tags: scala, mocking, default-value

I have the following trait (that will be implemented by a `java.util.prefs.Preferences` wrapper):

```
trait PreferencesMethods {
  def get(key: String, default: String = ""): String
  def getInt(key: String, default: Int = 0): Int
  def put(key: String, value: String)
  def putInt(key: String, value: Int)
}
```

I created an EasyMock of it like this:

```
val preferencesMock = EasyMock.createMock(classOf[PreferencesMethods])
```

I am calling it like this in my test case:

```
EasyMock.expect(preferencesMock.getInt("key")).andReturn(0)
```

and like this in the class-under-test:

```
preferences.getInt("key")
```

but EasyMock complains that I have an unexpected call to "getInt$default$2": "java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected method call getInt$default$2()"

How do I mock the default parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would be better off doing partial mock with easymock or look for more native scala solution like Borachio (http://www.paulbutcher.com/2011/02/announcing-borachio-native-scala-mocking/)